# Mysql dump containing empty lines

Tags: mysql, database

I am facing problem, where mysqldump(ing) my database behaves strange, with just one table in database. Table has nothing unusual configuration in it and all the columns are just basic stuff, expect it has two columns with longtext/text datatype, if that does matter somehow. Longtext column contains valid xml strings and text column contains valid json strings.

Problem is that produced dump file contains no inserts at all for that specific table. Dump file has sql lines for everything else. Dump file even has create table lines for that problematic table and all other mysql stuff, but insert lines are totally missing for that table. Instead of inserts, there is just huge amount of empty lines in the middle of dump file. Dump is done like this:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword dbname > dump.sql
```

I did notice, that when I add

```
--extended-insert=false
```

to my dump command, dump contains some insert rows. Rows with ids 1-7 are present, 8-9 are missing, 10 is present, 11 is missing, 12-13 are present etc... missing row insert lines are replaced by empty line in dump file.

Could anyone have any clue, what is happening here? For me, data seems not corrupted and it can be browsed via phpmyadmin interface.

Some facts about the case

- mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using
  readline 6.2
- Problem table engine is InnoDB
- Dump file size is around 1.7G
- Problem table has around 230.000 rows

Comment: Does `--extended-insert=FALSE --complete-insert=TRUE --compatible=ansi` help?

Comment: No it does not. Results are same like as they are with "--extended-insert=FALSE" option only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by inspecting dump file closer with different program. LogExpert has known bug of not showing lines with too many characters in it. Dump file was just fine and problem did not actually even exist.

Importing from dump file failed because of too small innodb buffer size in php.ini file. So there was two separated problems that confused me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, after long hours of troubleshooting, getting a blank dump file, it was disk space issues on the server where I am trying to take db dump.
Seems silly but posting may it helped.